# Are there any vegetarian or vegan alternatives to bone broth?

Tags: food, substitutes

*Sorry if my previous question was confusing. I've tried to clarify it.*

I did some reading, but am wondering if anyone would care to share what they've tried and if it provided any benefits. From foodrevolution.org, the benefits of bone broth: "...advocates say it can relieve joint pain and osteoarthritis, detoxify the liver, aid in wound healing, prevent aging skin, support digestive health, balance hormones, increase energy, strengthen bones, improve quality of sleep, alleviate symptoms from certain autoimmune conditions, and boost immune function."
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Can you clarify what characteristics of bone broth you are hoping to retain? Veggie broth would be an easy substitute for many recipes, so I'm not sure what more you are looking for :)

Comment: Please clarify and then I will reopen it to be able to get answers :)

Comment: Erica, I hope my edit has helped.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question after the Edit but please, be aware that many websites on the internet try to create hype around various "superfoods" and bone broth [seems to be one of them](https://time.com/4159156/bone-broth-health-benefits/). There is nothing intrinsically special about bone broth, no magical vitamin or protein that can't be gotten from anything else. As such, there is nothing to substitute, really. A well balanced vegetarian/vegan diet will cover the things that the bone broth provides quite well. If you like broths, there are many delicious vegetable ones.

Comment: Thank you, Alexander Rossa. I was looking to see if anyone had tried any alternatives and what benefits they'd seen through personal experience. Please delete my question, if you see fit to do so. I may have misunderstood what kind of questions I can ask.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa I think you could expand your comment into an answer -- helpful to both dial down the expectations of bone broth magic, and suggest alternative veggie broths :)

Comment: @Erica When I was about to post the reply I thought the same but the question was closed at that time so it wasn't possible. Will move the comment to a separate answer when I have a bit more time :).

Comment: @Andrea No problem at all, I don't think your question is fit for deletion by any means, just wanted to point out that many times there are sensational statements around foods that are nothing but ordinary, in order to sell.

Answer (score 8):

Moving my original comment as an answer since the question was reopened:

It's good to be aware that many websites on the internet try to create hype around various "superfoods" and bone broth [seems to be one of them](https://time.com/4159156/bone-broth-health-benefits/). There is [nothing intrinsically special about these foods](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3635479/) and the same goes for bone broth, it provides no magical vitamin or protein that can't be gotten from anything else. As such, there is nothing to substitute, really. A well balanced vegetarian/vegan diet will cover the things that the bone broth provides quite well. If you like broths, there are many delicious vegetable ones.

Answer (score 3):

Vegetable broth is an alternative to bone broth.

You can make vegetable broth in many ways:

1. You can buy vegetable stock (broth) pre-prepared in a carton or
2. Buy dry bouillon cubes or
3. Make your own [vegetable broth powder](https://eatingvibrantly.com/recipes/instant-homemade-vegetable-stock-powder/)
4. Make your own vegetable broth by [boiling vegetable trimmings](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/12982/basic-vegetable-stock/) (corn cobs, onion ends, pepper seeds, pea pods, leafy stems, potato parings, etc)

Comment: Can you please provide more details? We like more elaborate answers (providing more context, references whenever possible).

Comment: ok Alexei, done.